# NetworkX.rich_club_coefficient() throwing numpy.AxisError: axis -1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 0

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, networkx

I am having troubling understanding what I can do about this, or what it even means.

Here's my code:

```
g = nx.read_gml(testfile)
rc = nx.rich_club_coefficient(g)
```

Then, I recieve the error:

```
numpy.AxisError: axis -1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 0
```

I am not sure what in my graph is causing this.  I was hoping someone had experience with `nx.rich_club_coefficient` might be able to shine some light on this predicament.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you print the values of `g.edges` and `g.nodes` after `g = ...`? Also you can comment out line `rc = ...` to find out exactly which line raise this error.

Comment: Thanks for commenting!  `g.nodes` and `g.edges` will be a little tough.  Here is `nx.info(g)` : `Name: 
Type: Graph
Number of nodes: 4414
Number of edges: 210538
Average degree:  95.3956`

Also, thanks for the tip about commenting out the `rc`!

Comment: Can you copy full Traceback error with line numbers etc?

Comment: I figured it out.  It was the isolates in my network that didn't agree with the `nx.rich_club_cofficient`.  I added this line, `graph.remove_nodes_from(list(nx.isolates(graph)))`, and it works just fine now.  Thanks for commenting and trying to help.  That's what makes this site so amazing.  I will definitely remember that trick to see the line error too!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I have figured it out.

For some reason the isolates in the network were not playing nice with the function.

I added `graph.remove_nodes_from(list(nx.isolates(graph)))` and it works fine.

I hope this helps somebody else too.